# Diffusion current and depletion region with doping

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I've been told that depletion region width decreases when we increase doping in a P-N junction. But doesn't this contradicts the fact that diffusion current increases with current? I'm probably mixing things up. What I would like to know is:

1. How does diffusion current varies with doping
2. How does the width of depletion region varies with doping
3. How does the charge (and then, the electric field and the voltage) of depletion region varies with doping. Why is it said the voltage cannot increase more than $0.7$ V for a silicon junction?

Comment: The depletion region width increases until the field is large enough to counteract the diffusion current. Higher doping means more static charge per unit thickness, so you increase the built-in potential faster.

Comment: what about equilibrium state?